# links does not exist in query builder

Tags: laravel

I get this error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.
```

when I add this code

```
if ($request->has('colors')){
        $colorproduct = ColorProduct::with("product")
            ->WhereIn('color_id',explode(',', request()->input('colors')))->get();
        $colorproduct = array_unique($colorproduct->pluck("product_id")->toArray());
        $products = $products
            ->whereIn('id',$colorproduct);
    }
```

code to this query builder

```
       $products = QueryBuilder::for(Product::class)

        ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::exact('brand', 'brand_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('wristlet', 'wristlet_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('plate', 'plate_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('accuracy', 'accuracy_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('width', 'width_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('frame', 'fram_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('material', 'material_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('framwidth', 'framwidth_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('framweight', 'framweight_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('lensheight', 'lensheight_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('lenswidth', 'lenswidth_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('lengthface', 'lengthface_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('handlehinge', 'handlehinge_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('faceform', 'faceform_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('nasalwidth', 'nasalwidth_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('original', 'original_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('PD_range' ,'PD_range'),
            AllowedFilter::scope('min_price' ),
            AllowedFilter::scope('max_price' ),
            AllowedFilter::scope('min_pd' ),
            AllowedFilter::scope('max_pd' ),
            AllowedFilter::scope('min_lens' ),
            AllowedFilter::scope('max_lens' ),
        ])
        ->allowedSorts('price','created_at','available_id')
        ->defaultSort('price')
        ->with('category')->paginate('15')
        ->appends(request()->query());


    if ($request->has('colors')){
        $colorproduct = ColorProduct::with("product")
            ->WhereIn('color_id',explode(',', request()->input('colors')))->get();
        $colorproduct = array_unique($colorproduct->pluck("product_id")->toArray());
        $products = $products
            ->whereIn('id',$colorproduct);
    }
```

color product is table interface and when filter product by color id get this error

Comment: are you passing something to a view and calling `links` on it?  what ever you are calling `links` on isn't a Paginator, just a regular Eloquent Collection

Comment: {{$products->links()}}

Comment: yes in blade use links

Comment: and which of these variables you have above are you passing to your view as `products`?

Comment: $products pass to view

Comment: everything works perfectly but when I want get color request this error show